# Get specific data from python dictionary to form another dictionary

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I already have a nested dictionary received after parsing XML, I want specific key value pairs from it and to form their dictionary.

**This is the XML parsed by python code using `xmltodict`:**

```
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
OrderedDict([(u'OEM-NAME', OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'VOLKSWAGEN'), (u'CAR-TYPE', [OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'Sedan'), (u'Car', [OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'Ameo'), (u'fuel', OrderedDict([(u'ABS', u'available'), (u'AWD', u'not available'), (u'price', OrderedDict([(u'@DEST', u'xyz'), ('#text', u'5.53Lakh')])), ('#text', u'petrol')]))]), OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'Jetta'), (u'fuel', OrderedDict([(u'ABS', u'available'), (u'AWD', u'available'), (u'price', OrderedDict([(u'@DEST', u'uvw'), ('#text', u'7.0Lakh')])), ('#text', u'disel')]))])])]), OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'Sport utility vehicle'), (u'Car', [OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'Tiguan'), (u'fuel', OrderedDict([(u'ABS', OrderedDict([(u'@DEST', u'hgj'), ('#text', u'available')])), (u'AWD', u'not available'), (u'price', u'11Lakh'), ('#text', u'petrol')]))]), OrderedDict([(u'@title', u'T-Roc'), (u'fuel', OrderedDict([(u'ABS', u'available'), (u'AWD', u'available'), (u'price', u'7Lakh'), ('#text', u'disel')]))])])])])]))])
```

**Required data from output:**

If in fuel tag text is "petrol", get name of car from CAR tag, text from ABS tag and Price tag.

**I.e:**

```
data = {Ameo:{ABS : available , price : 5.53Lakh}, Tiguan: {ABS : available , price :11lakh}}
```